# How to import ESRI Ascii format into GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, esri-ascii-raster

I need to take a set of datafiles, generated by our sensor system that reads GPR (Ground penetrating Radar) deviations over a surface as we drive along.  I have discrete readings from a set of sensors and can accurately place them relative to the GPS unit spitting out location values once a second, along with track and speed in meters/second.  I want to create an [Esri ASCII](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000z000000) data file for each second, with each row representing the sensor values along the rail, with one row representing all 16 sensors (spaced equally apart), read every 1/25th of a second.  I can figure out the offsets to accurately place the sensors, in meters, relative to the GPS unit and as each sensor is read.  It is relatively easy to then figure out the location for each reading along the track the GPS unit is measuring in Meters/second, thus arriving at the separation, in meters, between rows of generated sensor data.

What I am having a hard time doing is converting this information into [ESRI ASCII format](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000000z000000), specifically the CELL size.  My sensor rack is about 4 meters long and the GPS unit is centrally located with a small offset forward of the sensor array.  How can I determine the cell size for my many rows of sensor data?  I will locate this data with the GPS output, and have no problem calculating the boundaries for the one second time period.  What has me stumped is the cell size.

Example data:
Sensors 1 - 16
232.2 233. 244.4 256.8 260.1 ..... 211.5
next row 0.1 meter later
next row 0.1 meter later
25 rows in all

Sensors separated 0.25 meter from each other

Any ideas folks?  What does that pesky cell size have to be and more importantly, how did you figure out that number?

Comment: My first thought is that you have non-square cells: 0.1 m x 0.25 m. Velocity of device may affect the 0.1 m value. Or, build the sensor data as vector points, then convert to raster. For the cell size Q, does this help? http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Cell%20size%20of%20raster%20data

Comment: When "converting this information into ERSI [sic] ASCII format" what GIS software and version are you using?

Comment: I am going to import this ERSI Ascii file (its actually ARC Ascii format as well) into GRASS GIS as an overlay of data on a USGS map.  I'm using GRASS 6.4.3, which is fine for my purposes.  What I need to know is the CELL value I should put in my ASCII file.  It is not clear to me if the CELL value is in DEGREES or METERS.  Once I know that I can figure out the rest myself, with your sage advice and expert help, of course.

Comment: MKennedy is right, the cells won't be SQUARE, but that can't be helped at this point and isn't really important.  We'll up the resolution later.  All I want to do at this point is demonstrate proof of concept, that we can overlay sensor data on a USGS raster map.

Comment: Given that my cells will be .25m by .1m what sort of cell size does that translate to?  And how was that figure derived?

Comment: If the file's coordinates are in degrees, the cell size must be in degrees.  A raster is a raster; the coordinates are defined by either URX/URY/LLX/LLY or URX/URY/PIXELX/PIXELY, and then all else is mapped to pixels.  You can't capture individual coordinates in a raster; maybe what you want is a TIN (vector), which can be interpolated to a continuous raster.

Comment: http://spavicic.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/create-gridraster-from-ascii-file-using.html

Comment: where can I find the documentation for these Name variables?  Are they part of the ARC/ERIS Ascii file format?  I have never seen them in any definition I've found on the web.  Thanks for clearing up the CELL metric.  My TOPLEFT location will be in Decimal degrees, so the cell size is in decimal degrees as well.  Right?

Comment: There are no variables with those names; I was speaking genericly.  All you get is what is in the .hdr, and what is in the world file, both of which have links below.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using an ASCII file, which can get quite large, use a [binary file in BIP layout](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000010000000), so you can place the sensor band values next to each other.   This format also allows rectangular (non-square) pixels, which the ASCII grid loader does *not* support.

Comment: BIP looks good and not difficult to convert to from the data I have generated.  HOWEVER, how does one register this BIP file with the GPS coordinates I am generating as I move merrily along over the surface of the earth?  BIP seems to capture a sequence of data rows just fine, allowing me to make a very long 'strip' of data consisting of hundreds of rows of data, instead of just 25/second, as I was going to do with ASCII.  But there seems to be no GPS/Lat/Lon registry capability for the BIP format.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: Another proviso is that tracking is never 'straight line', it deviates, around obstructions, trees, etc, and thus I must accommodate changes in Track/Speed for every reading once a second, thus my preference for ASCII format to provide the most accurate location info for my sensor readings.

Comment: ALL raster formats are continuous.  If you have discountinuous data, a vector format might be more appropriate.
If you just want to anchor a corner to the globe, then you would use either the ulxmap/ulymax/xdim/ydim parameters, or if there's rotation, by creating a ".biw" world file  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file

Comment: I looked at the ulxmap/ulymax/xdim/ydim variables but they seem to indicate the internal 'size' of the map and its representative pixels.  I don't understand how internally sizing raster data will 'anchor' a map to the real world and it's Lat/Lon values.  What did I miss?

Comment: I will look into vector map representation of the data, does anyone have a format that is easy to master, relatively?  My data example is shown above.

Comment: "ulxmap—The x-axis map coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel." Looks like an anchor to me.  Note that it's offset xdmin/2 to the right of the outer UL corner. Same deal with ulymap/ydim.

Comment: Then the ulxmap coordinate would be defined as a lat/lon pair in decimal degrees, correct?  That would work like this  ulxmap = 20.399922 ulymap = 122.9201242.  The devil is in the details like the correct syntax, value separators, etc.  Just saying there's a variable of this name only gets me halfway there.

Comment: Latitude is a Y value, and longitude is an X, so you've got your coordinates swapped (there is no 123 degrees North).  It's a whitespace separator, one pair per line, and the properties are case-insensitive, so the format description and examples should get you more than halfway there.  You should of course prototype with small subsets until you iron out the details.

Comment: That should answer my question about ulxmap and ulymap  However now I wonder about the PIXEL offset value, its in degrees, correct?  This makes the PIXEL distance to the right hand edge = 16 PIXELS (the width of my sensor array which is 4 meters) MINUS 1/2 PIXEL to the right of the UL corner (which is what ulxmap and ulymap point to)  Correct?

Comment: ulxmap and ulymap point to the *center* of the upper-left pixel, which is offset 1/2 the pixel width (xdim, in mapping units -- degrees) to the right and 1/2 the pixel height (ydim) down from the upper-left *corner*.